# Vaadin saves the request to its resource, not the page during authorization

Tags: vaadin-flow

After updating vaadin version to 24.3.5 vaadin for some reason saves to the cache a request to an internal resource instead of the page visited by an anonymous user. So after authorization user sees vaadinPush.js file.

In this case we use vaadin.url-mapping and this request to the resource goes without url-mapping.

In fact, I don't even know where to start digging through the source code to override the class or method that calls this save.

Expected behavior: vaadin saves the request only to the page and not to internal resources

Same issue as [#13190](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13190)

Comment: Same issue as [#13190](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13190)